# Android: Enlarging an image on click

Tags: android, imageview

i am making an android app in which in  need that   , when the user clicks image I want it to open up in the full screen. How do I accomplish this?
Can anyone help me over this? 
Thanks

Comment: You can display it using a webview in a new fullscreen activity
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941009/android-easiest-way-to-make-a-webview-display-a-bitmap

Answer (score 3):

Get image Id of selected image then pass that image id to FullImage activity using Intent. Display image in that activity using ImageView.

follow coding like this

Activity1  // where images are available..

```
Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Full.class); 
fullScreenIntent.putExtra(Full.class.getName(),imageId);
```

in the FullImage Activity..add this coding.

```
int imageId1 = intent.getIntExtra(Full.class.getName(),default1); 
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId1);
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
myimage.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
myimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Comment: what is default1 here? and if we need to get images from different classes i.e. in different activities the same thing is to be done.

Comment: are u using gridview for displaying small images or not if u are using grindview u will get imageid from that.

Comment: No i am not using gridview i am simply adding images to rows in table

Comment: why like that use grid view that is easy to display images and getting large image from that.

Comment: Actually that is my requirement

Comment: yes I am getting image id. i tried the above code but it is giving me the following exception:       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emx.OnDaMove/com.emx.OnDaMove.FullImageActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4

Comment: see my new answer, i hope u will get now. if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in an easy way.

If you have other views on your activity just set their Visibility to gone and make imageview fill parent on Click event.

Comment: make a boolean check which you can use to check current state. Make it true if on full screen and vice versa.
Even you can put animation for hiding/showing your other views.

Comment: Canm you please tell me how to make that boolean check

Comment: o dear its easy.
Just make a boolean variable like Boolean fullScreen; and make it false on activity create. Now on Click listener before going to full screen first check the boolean value. If it is false then call the full screen function and make it true. Now on the next tap the control will goto else statement where you can call the small screen function and set the fullScreen boolean false...

Hope its enough for you now.