# How do I program a Scrollable SurfaceView in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, scroll, surfaceview

I am trying to draw an image that is larger than the screen, and let the user scroll around it. The image is some graphs that are calculated by my code from some data. (This is in Android using Java).

What I want is a View (actually a SurfaceView) that can be scrolled by the user. I have tried putting a SurfaceView inside a ScrollView but the whole image drawn by the SurfaceView is very large and so (a) there are performance issues as my app is drawing the whole SurfaceView when it should only need to do the part that is in the viewport and (b) my app crashes with "dimensions too large... out of memory" errors.

It would be best for me if the View could implement scrolling (vertical only) and then pass the y-value to my code so it could draw the visible part of my image in the viewport.

Alternatively I could capture the 'mouse' events and calculate the y-value myself.

Does anyone have any code so that I can do this?

Update: I should clarify, the image is drawn by my program code using Canvas.drawLine() and the like. I can calculate which parts of the image fit within my viewport, provided I have the state of the scroll as a y-value, and I can calculate the absolute y-coordinate of each point by subtracting scroll y-value. What I need is something that works to find when the user scrolls the image and what the resulting y-value is. A scrollbar would also be nice.

Update: I am using SurfaceView so that I can update the image from another Thread and so improve user interface performance.

Comment: why there has to be a SurfaceView? why dont you just create a custom View with overrode onDraw ?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why.

Comment: ok i didnt try that with SurfaceView but that should work the same as the SurfaceView extends View: just use `View.scrollBy()`/`View.scrollTo()` in order to show some specific part of your view

Comment: now i'm wiser since i tested the SurfaceView and scrollTo/scrollBy: unfortunately it does not work, sorry, you need to `translate()` your Canvas by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really have just a draw content... you don't need a scrollable client then...

- have a model (x,y,lines, etc)
- have a pan & zoom
- draw a **scaled/zoomed** instance of the model

just draw the content (sorry - no scroller in this solution)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean isProcessed = scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (isProcessed) {

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            tap( event.getX(), event.getY() );
            mode = DRAG_OR_TAP;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG_OR_TAP) {
                doPan(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    myView.scale(currentPan, currentScaleFactor);

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

private void doPan(float panX, float panY) {        
    currentPan.x = currentPan.x + panX;
    currentPan.y = currentPan.y + panY;

}

private void tap(float x, float y) {
    ...
}
```

and last not least use the scaleListener

```
private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        float value = detector.getScaleFactor();
        currentScaleFactor = currentScaleFactor * value;

        // don't let the object get too small or too large.
        boolean doesntMatch = false;
        if (currentScaleFactor < 1f || currentScaleFactor > 20f){
            currentScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(currentScaleFactor, 20f));
            doesntMatch = true;
        }

        if(!doesntMatch){
            //scale the viewport as well
            currentPan.x = currentPan.x*value;
            currentPan.y = currentPan.y*value;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this as a basis for my code (I only need vertical pan so I have simplified the code a bit).

Comment: to be honest - this **is** part of my programm, but i really must confess that also i copied that code snipped from somebody else (and also i did adjust it a little) ^^ good luck for your app!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a WebView to display an image

- provides pan
- provides zoom
- no library required
- has a scrollbar

[Android: Easiest way to make a WebView display a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941009/android-easiest-way-to-make-a-webview-display-a-bitmap)

i'm not sure if i really hit your question...

Comment: I am not displaying a web page. Although I could in theory display my image as an <img> tag, this would be very inefficient as I am updating the image all the time.